# How to commit a list of @todo types directly in the project (especially with PhpStorm)

Tags: phpstorm, todo

The `.editorconfig` file is a file that, once read by the IDE, can format the text in the right way helping maintaining a conform code styling.

Now, I'd like to use some custom @todos patterns like `@feature`, `@bug`, `@security`, something like the tags in GitHub.

But configuring those custom @todos each time is time consuming and not so funny.

So, is there some sort of configuration file I can create to automatically make those custom @todos patterns recognizable by PhpStorm?

Comment: Does .`editorconfig` file spec allows to define TODO patterns? AFAIK - no

Comment: But I didn' mean using .editorconfig o.O

Comment: My fault -- I've somehow misread the question and was under an impression that you wanted to use that file. Back to the question -- you can, but it's an IDE-wide setting as far as I can see and will affect all projects. So once configured it will be available in all projects. `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2016.2\config\options\editor.xml` -- TODO settings are stored there (that's for Windows and PhpStorm 2016.2; for other OS -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Comment: Mmm, so I should anyway copy the file or hardlink it in the project. But anyway the editor of someone else who clone the repo isn't able to load it. And if the developer copy the file, it will overwrite all other settings... A bit useless... Possible there isn't a way to do this? Am I the only one in the world who has this needs? :(

Comment: Well -- there is no per-project TODO patterns. At very least I see no mentions of such stuff in any project-specific files and all changes get saved in IDE-wide settings. So you have no other choice: either leave it for user to figure it out (he will look at it when (and if) he needs them) .. or provide special readme kind of file (e.g. `docs\jetbrains.md`) where you can describe these steps (but still -- it would be up to user to set it up).